# Access global namespace from proxy header

Tags: c++, namespaces, redefinition

I have a namespace called "access" in project. This is actually used in many places inside the project. Currently I am writing unit test case for this project. I my unit test, the io.h file getting included from the UT frame work. This io file contains c function called "access". So when I tried to include both the io file and one of my project file, I got the re-definition error for "access".

So I tried to use the proxy header for solving the above problem. For proxy header I included the frame work header file in a namespace to avoid re-definition error.

But that frame work file accessing some global namespaces. So I am getting more issues with that. Is there any way to solve the issue without renaming the namespace.

Here is my sample code.

```
#pragma once

#include "io.h"
#include <iostream>

class Class01
{
public:
    Class01(void);
    ~Class01(void);
    void function() {
        std::cout<< " Write something";}
```

};

```
#pragma once

namespace access
{

  class Class02
  {
  public:
    Class02(void);
    ~Class02(void);
  };
}
```

proxy header

```
  #pragma once

    namespace sample
    {
        #include "Class01.h"
    };
    #include "Class02.h"


// NamespaceRedef.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
//#include "Class02.h"
//#include "Class01.h"
#include "proxyHeader.h"

using namespace sample;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code, I got the following error...

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2039: 'acosf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2873: 'acosf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2039: 'asinf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2873: 'asinf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2039: 'atanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'atanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2039: 'atan2f' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'atan2f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration  crosoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'atanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2039: 'atan2f' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'atan2f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration

Comment: You can always access the global namespace from anywhere using the scope-operator, as in `::some_symbol_in_the_global_namespace`. ***However*** that's not really the problem you have. The problem you have is that you wrap the *standard* namespace `std` inside another namespace. You should not do that! Using `#include` of system headers (directly or *indirectly* like you do) inside another user-defined namespace is a big no-no.

Comment: But that the idea of using proxy header. or proxy header is only for user defined file ?

Comment: It seems you don't really understand what a proxy header is.   The code you are showing is something completely different.

Comment: you are right. I just heard the term when I searched for solution this problem. And I got one example some what saying like this